# C# VSTO Outlook 2007: <dll> is not a valid Office Add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, ms-office, add-in

Hi i am developing Outlook 2007 Add-in in Visual Studio 2008. When I press F5 in VS editor, Outlook is normally opened with my plugin.

But if I want to add plugin manually from Outlook (Tools -> Trust center -> Add Ins...) and select my plugin from build path ....\bin\Release\plugin.dll

**This messagebox is shown: "....\bin\Release\plugin.dll" is not a valid Office Add-in.**

I have NOT this plugin in disabled items. (Help -> Disabled Items)

I searched many threads on internet with same problem but no soulution. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Never add your add-in manually via that dialog - it's completely useless.  Add-ins need to be properly registered with Windows Installer packages (or when debugging in Visual Studio) to be loaded properly.

Comment: Thank you, and is there any tutorial how to add my Addin in Visual Studio setup project (which creates .msi setup files)

Comment: Here's a great reference: Deploying a Visual Studio Tools for the Office System 3.0 Solution for the 2007 Microsoft Office System Using Windows Installer (Part 1 of 2): 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc563937(office.12).aspx